# Rails - Changing association doesn't mark object as dirty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**Edit**: Clarifications added

Given the following two classes

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When I change a bar on a foo, I would like a way to see that the foo instance has changed:

```
foo = Foo.find(x)
foo.bar      # returns #<Bar id:1>
foo.bar = Bar.new
foo.changed? # returns false
foo.changes  # returns an empty hash
```

I don't want to set bar_id as dirty (because it hasn't changed)  It would be nice to have the following:

```
foo.changed? # returns true
foo.changes  # returns {:bar => [#<Bar id: 1>, nil]}
```

Is there a clever way to hack this into Rails?  Is there a reason this is not part of Rails?

Comment: old_bar and Bar.find(y) are the same? In other words, reassigning the same bar again to f.bar?. If they are different, it should return changed. It does for me.

Comment: SMathew: If you attach a bar with an id, it shows up in changes.  If you attach a bar that doesn't yet have an ID, it shows that nothing has changed.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem today and after running through the rails-source i found a workaround that should do what you had in mind, if i got your question the right way.

Transferred to your example the code should look like that:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar

  def info
    bar.info
  end

  def info=(val)
    @changed_attributes[:info] = self.info unless val == self.info
    self.time_entry.update_attributes! :info => val
  end
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :info
end
```

This way you can call .changed? and .changes on objects of the Foo-class.

hope this helps even if the answer comes a bit late :)

kind regards
christian

*btw. sorry for the poor english. i am working on that as much as on my ruby-skills ;)*

Answer (score 2):

What version of Rails are you using? When I tested it, it does report true.

Anyway, I am not sure if an after assign callback is available for belongs_to yet. There was a ticket for this
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/586

If not, you can just override the assign method
(I haven't tried this before, but I think it will work :) so please let me know)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar

  def bar=(b)
    bar_id_will_change! unless bar_id == b.id
    super        
  end

end
```

Update: Just read your question again, and I am not even sure if I understood all of it. You want it to still report true if it hasn't changed? Even when assigning the same object again right? in which case you can remove the `unless bar_id == b.id` part

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I responded above in an edit to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Due to changes to `@changed_attributes` in Rails 5.1, I had to resort to using a virtual attribute (attr_accessor) to indicate the changed association after checks. This might be better in the long run compared to messing with Rails internals related to `ActiveRecord::Dirty`