# Rails nested_attributes_for not working on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

This is my first question around here, so hopefully it will work out. I've looked around for someone for a similar problem, but haven't found anything so far. I'm sure it is something simple but I just can't see it right now!

I'm trying to save nested attributes for a model in rails 3.2.11, but the operation just works when *creating* the nested object, but not when *updating* it.

Here is the code for the 2 models Im working with

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :opening_times
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :opening_times, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :opening_times_attributes

...

class OpeningTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  attr_accessible :start_date, :end_date

  attr_accessible :day, :start_time, :end_time
  attr_writer :day, :start_time, :end_time

  before_save :set_dates

...

  def set_dates
    day = Date.parse(@day)
    start_time = Time.parse(@start_time)
    end_time = Time.parse(@end_time)

    start_date = "#{day.day}/#{day.month}/#{day.year} #{start_time.hour}:#{start_time.min}"
    self.start_date = DateTime.parse(start_date)

    end_date = "#{day.day}/#{day.month}/#{day.year} #{end_time.hour}:#{end_time.min}"
    self.end_date = DateTime.parse(end_date)
  end
```

So when I try to create an opening time through a property using rails console, it works:

```
1.9.3p125 :006 > p = Property.find(9)
1.9.3p125 :006 > p.opening_times_attributes = [{"day"=>"27/02/2013", "start_time"=>"11:30",     "end_time"=>"12:30", "_destroy"=>"false"}]
 => [{"day"=>"27/02/2013", "start_time"=>"11:30", "end_time"=>"12:30", "_destroy"=>"false"}] 
1.9.3p125 :007 > p.save!
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 Suburb Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "suburbs".* FROM "suburbs" WHERE "suburbs"."name" = 'BARREN GROUNDS' LIMIT 1
 SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "opening_times" ("end_date", "property_id", "start_date") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["end_date", Wed, 27 Feb 2013 12:30:00 UTC +00:00], ["property_id", 9], ["start_date", Wed, 27 Feb 2013 11:30:00 UTC +00:00]]
 (2.8ms)  commit transaction
 => true
```

But when I try to update an existing nested object (passing id in the hash), it doesnt do anything

```
1.9.3p125 :037 > p.opening_times
 => [#<OpeningTime id: 12, property_id: 9, start_date: "2013-02-27 11:00:00", end_date: "2013-02-27 13:00:00">] 
1.9.3p125 :038 > p.opening_times_attributes = [{"day"=>"27/02/2013", "start_time"=>"11:30", "end_time"=>"12:30", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>12}]
 => [{"day"=>"27/02/2013", "start_time"=>"11:30", "end_time"=>"12:30", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>12}] 
1.9.3p125 :039 > p.save!
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
Suburb Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "suburbs".* FROM "suburbs" WHERE "suburbs"."name" = 'BARREN GROUNDS' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
1.9.3p125 :040 > exit
```

Based on what I've read so far (i.e http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes), this should work for both operations.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

[EDIT]

Based on @jvnill's suggestion, it seems that the before_save callback is not being called on update. I've added a workaround to explicitly call set_dates when any of the fields is updated and then it works.

```
def day=(day)
  @day = day
  set_dates unless (@day.blank? || @start_time.blank? || @end_time.blank?)
end

def start_time=(start_time)
  @start_time = start_time
  set_dates unless (@day.blank? || @start_time.blank? || @end_time.blank?)
end

def end_time=(end_time)
  @end_time = end_time
  set_dates unless (@day.blank? || @start_time.blank? || @end_time.blank?)
end
```

It doesn't completely solve the problem since now the validation doesn't work seamlessly, and it seems like I'm having to manually do the work that AR should be doing.

Comment: i'm assuming that you're building the start and end times on the `set_dates` callback.  can you check that method and see that the update goes through it without any issues?

Comment: I've checked, and that method doesnt get called on the update. It does go through normally in the creation (as in the example) though.

Comment: so that's where your issue is.  can you include that method in your question?

Comment: not sure I follow, but I've added the method to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the answers above, I've realised that you have to explicitly tell AR that a field is changing when some virtual attribute is set, otherwise the before_save callback is never invoked.

It's not great, but the work around I've found for the problem is to call {attr}_will_change! whenever a virtual attribute was set:

```
def day=(val)
  unless val == self.day
    start_date_will_change!
    end_date_will_change!
  end
  @day = val
end

def start_time=(val)
  start_date_will_change! unless val == self.start_time
  @start_time = val
end

def end_time=(val)
  end_date_will_change! unless val == self.end_time
  @end_time = val
end
```

Thanks to all for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see that you can update your child model without using the nested attributes first. It's possible your validation or callback code is stopping the update and there's nothing wrong with your `nested_attributes` call.

So, does this work?

```
> o = p.opening_times.first
> o.update_attributes({"day"=>"27/02/2013", "start_time"=>"11:30", "end_time"=>"12:30"})
```

If not, disable your validations and callbacks and see if the nested_attributes passes through correctly.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so it looks like the problem is with the nested attributes call. What happens if you try this?

```
> p.update_attributes(opening_times_attributes: [{"day"=>"27/02/2013", "start_time"=>"11:30", "end_time"=>"12:30", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>12} ])
```

Note, that I'm calling `update_attributes` and not setting `opening_times_attributes`

**EDIT 2:**

If you can destroy the record via nested attributes I suspect something is rejecting your changes on the child model. Have you checked for validation errors? Have you tried updating just 1 attribute?

Comment: (0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.3ms)  UPDATE "opening_times" SET "start_date" = '2013-02-27 11:30:00.000000', "end_date" = '2013-02-27 12:30:00.000000' WHERE "opening_times"."id" = 12
(2.4ms)  commit transaction

Comment: Nothing again..(0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Suburb Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "suburbs".* FROM "suburbs" WHERE "suburbs"."name" = 'BARREN GROUNDS' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction

Comment: Can you destroy the record?

Comment: Scratching my head... If you disable the `set_date` callback can you update via nested attributes?

Comment: Just updated the question. If I force the attributes to be updated when the virtual ones change, then saving works, so it seems its related to when the before_save callback is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I now know your issue.  the `_save` callbacks are not triggered when nothing was changed in the record.  since you are calling `before_save` without really changing anything on the parent model, the callback is not triggered.  try using `before_validation` instead of `before_save`.

Comment: If that's the case, that could be the issue, but changing it to before_validation didn't work either. I've tried to update it together with something on the model and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Just updated the question. If I force the attributes to be updated when the virtual ones change, then saving works, so it seems its related to when the before_save callback is executed

Comment: can you try out the first answer in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460667/rails-changing-association-doesnt-mark-object-as-dirty

Comment: Thanks! That exact solution didnt work (time_entry doesnt exist?), but solved the problem by calling {attr}_will_change for the fields affected in every virtual attribute setter. Will post the answer to it but unfortunately have to wait 5 hours for it (dont have enough reputation! :P) Thanks a lot for your help