# How to find the changes of associated model's record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two model like below,

orders table attributes:

```
#  order_cost          :float
#  order_number        :string(255)
```

order_items table attributes:

```
#  order_id      :integer
#  price         :float
#  qty           :integer
#  name          :string
```

Association: "Order has_many Order_items"

I want to find out any changes made in order_items from order.

Consider "Order 1" has "4 order_items". In that, 2nd order_item.name is changed & 3rd order_item.qty changed.

Now my question, How to find Order 1 associated record changes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I read it completely, we can't find the changes of associated models data.

Comment: He asked about the associated records. The documentation makes no mention of how to track changes on associated records.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want a record of the changes that took in your database.  If so, there's a gem called paper_trail that can help you with this.

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer would help. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13143304/2533958)

Apart from this I think there is no direct path to monitor changes of an association.